# lua ftp.get сохранение в файл

Tags: lua

Пример `ftp.get` из учебника:

```
-- load the ftp support
local ftp = require("socket.ftp")

-- Log as user "anonymous" on server "ftp.tecgraf.puc-rio.br",
-- and get file "lua.tar.gz" from directory "pub/lua" as binary.

f, e = ftp.get("ftp://ftp.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/pub/lua/lua.tar.gz;type=i")
```

В результате выполнения получу содержимое файла `lua.tar.gz` в переменной `f`. А как сделать чтобы файл сохранился локально на диске? В случае если `lua.tar.gz` будет, к примеру, размером в 1Gb, то это оперативка забивается. Через гугл ответа не смог найти.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В расширенной версии этой функции есть  параметр `sink` через который можно буферизовать чтение и эти буфера писать в файл.

http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/old/luasocket-2.0-beta/ftp.html

http://lua-users.org/wiki/FiltersSourcesAndSinks